# How to change the position of a product in a category

Tags: magento2

As the title says, i want to change the position of a single product in category. The only think i have found is this method setPostedProducts. But it sets for all products, which is useless for me. Because it will take a long time until i get respons.

The code looks like this now.

```
foreach($o["categories"] as $cats) {
        $cat = $cats;
        if(isset($this->categoryList[$cat["path"]]) && !empty($this->categoryList[$cat["path"]])) {

            try {
                $category = $this->catRepo->get($this->categoryList[$cat["path"]]);
                $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

                $productPositions[$product->getId()] = $cat["position"];

                $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
                $this->catRepo->save($category);
            } catch(\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->info("error updating category position for " . $sku);
                $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

This method updates the position for all products.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the category resource model.

So add this in your class

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category
 */
private $categoryResource;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category $categoryResource,
    ...
) {
    ....
    $this->categoryResource = $categoryResource; 
    ....
}
```

and in your method build the array with all the positions you want to change

Something like this:

```
$data = [
    [
         'category_id' => 4,
         'product_id' => 1,
         'position' => 10
    ],
    [
         'category_id' => 6,
         'product_id' => 1,
         'position' => 10
    ],
    ....
];
```

then call this

```
if (count($data) > 0) {
    $connection = $this->categoryResource->getConnection();
    $table = $this->categoryResource->getCategoryProductTable();
    $connection->insertOnDuplicate($table, $data, ['position']);
}
```

Comment: I tried but got this error

            $this->terminate($e); -> undified method call.

On this line -> $table = $this->categoryResource()->getCategoryProductTable();

Comment: Sorry. It should be categoryResource. Without `()`